# Oracle select table name with results

Tags: oracle, join

TABLE_A and TABLE_B both contain a columns "ORDER_NUM" and "PART_NUM"

You can join these two tables by "ORDER_NUM", but I also need the table name in my results.

I want to display the results in the following way:

```
ORDER_NUM | TABLE_NAME | PART_NUM
---------------------------------
700       | TABLE_A    | 001
700       | TABLE_A    | 002
700       | TABLE_A    | 003
700       | TABLE_B    | 004
700       | TABLE_B    | 005
700       | TABLE_B    | 006
```

Is this possible?

The most I can get is "ORDER_NUM" and "PART_NUM" together, but not the table name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select order_num, 'TABLE_A' as table_name, part_num
from table_a
union all
select order_num, 'TABLE_B', part_num
from table_b;
```